# How to create and run a lightweight internal RSS feed

Tags: rss, blogging

I have the idea to create a very simple tech update feed for internal collaboration in our company. To do this, I'm looking for the easiest way of writing messages that then get syndicated as an RSS feed. Something like a mini blogging tool. The simpler, the better.

Enter title, body and send, all subscribers of the feed get the new message. Sort of like Twitter without using Twitter. It has to be a purely web-based solution!

Any tips, ideas, experiences?

Comment: What Operating System are you on, in case it'll not be web-based?

Comment: @Daniel: It has to be web based, I'm anti-desktop, I want to be as mobile as possible.

Comment: That might have been a good requirement to add to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [Posterous](http://posterous.com). It's a minimal blogging site, plus you can create groups or set up a [private site with a private RSS feed](http://posterous.com/help/private_sites).

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually Posterous is perfect for this, not least because it provides private feeds without authentication, which was one of the problems with most other solutions.